# Instantiating an object in one line

Tags: c#

How could I instantiate the Flights in one line?

```
public class Flights
{
    public RouteInformation routeInformation { get; set; }
    public string FlightNumber { get; set; }
}
public class RouteInformation
{
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public string Destination { get; set; }
}
```

I want to instantiate the Flights in one line

```
    var flights = new Flights {  
                  new RouteInformation
                  {
                       Origin="IKA",
                       Destination="IST"
                  },

                   FlightNumber="123",
            };
```

But I got `Invalid initializer member declarator.`

Answer (score 2):

```
       var flights = new Flights {
              routeInformation = new RouteInformation
              {
                   Origin="IKA",
                   Destination="IST"
              },

               FlightNumber="123",
        };
```

You forgot "routeInformation ="